# how to loop a dataframe with increment factor based on a particular column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe I am working with looks like this:

```
                vid2  COS      fsim   FWeight
0  -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61    2  0.253792  0.750000
1  -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61    2  0.192565  0.250000
2    -_hbPLsZvvo_5_8    2  0.562707  0.333333
3    -_hbPLsZvvo_5_8    2  0.179969  0.666667
4  -_hbPLsZvvo_18_25    1  0.275962  0.714286
```

Here, 
the features have the following meanings:

*FWeight* - weight of each fragment (or row)

*fsim* - similarity score between the two columns *cap1* and *cap2*

The weighted formula is:
[image: Weighted formula]

```
For example, 
For vid2 "-_aaMGK6GGw_57_61", COS = 2
Thus, the two rows with vid2 comes under this.

   fsim       FWeight
0  0.253792   0.750000
1  0.192565   0.250000

The calculated value vid_score needs to be 
vid_score(1st video) = (fsim[0] * FWeight[0] + fsim[1] * FWeight[1])/(FWeight[0] + FWeight[1])

The expected output value vid_score for vid2 = -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61 is 
(0.750000) * (0.253792) + (0.250000) * (0.192565) 
= 0.238485 (Final value)
```

For some videos, this COS = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
Thus this needs to be dynamic

I am trying to calculate the weighted similarity score for each video ID that is *vid2* here. However, there are a number of captions and weights respectively for each video. It varies, some have 2, some 1, some 3, etc. This number of segments and captions has been stored in the feature *COS* (that is, count of segments).

I want to iterate through the dataframe where score for each video is stored as a weighted average score of the *fsim* (fragment similarity score). But the number of iteration is not regular.

I have tried this code. But I am not able to iterate dynamically with the iteration factor being *COS* instead of just a constant value

```py
vems_score = 0.0

video_scores = []

for i, row in merged.iterrows():
    vid_score = 0.0
    total_weight = 0.0

    for j in range(row['COS']):
        total_weight = total_weight + row['FWeight']
        vid_score = vid_score + (row['FWeight'] * row['fsim'])

    i = i + row['COS']

    vid_score = vid_score/total_weight
    video_scores.append(vid_score)

print(video_scores)
```

Comment: What is your formula for _weighted similarity score_?

Comment: Create a two/three columns' dummy dataframe with COS,  FWeight, fsim, etc being the only columns and keep around 5 rows. Use this example data to explain what you expect. Also provide the expected output for the dummy dataframe. Your current data is not reproducible and difficult to read. Please try and reduce the unnecessary details.

Comment: @CypherX I have edited the data. Please take a look now. If there is some issue in understanding my question., I would modify it further. Thanks

Comment: So you final result will look like? Will you have vid2 as the unique value in each row post-processing?

Comment: @CypherX, Yes, a list or maybe dataframe with vid2 and its score, vid_score

Comment: @CypherX The main issue is that, COS is different for every vid2, so the loop needs to run dynamic number of times, it is not a constant. I am not able to incorporate for loop accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213482/discussion-between-cypherx-and-vaidehi).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sol which you can modify/optimize to your needs.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
def computeSim():    
    vid=[1,1,2,2,3]
    cos=[2,2,2,2,1]
    fsim=[0.25,.19,.56,.17,.27]
    weight = [.75,.25,.33,.66,.71]
    df= pd.DataFrame({'vid':vid,'cos':cos,'fsim':fsim,'fw':weight})
    print(df)
    df2 = df.groupby('vid')
    similarity=[]
    for group in df2:
        similarity.append( np.sum(group[1]['fsim']*group[1]['fw'])/ np.sum(group[1]['fw']))
    return similarity
```

output:

0.235

0.30000000000000004

0.27

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Try this with your data. I assume that you stored the dataframe as `df`.

```py
df['Prod'] = df['fsim']*df['FWeight']
grp = df.groupby(['vid2', 'COS'])
result = grp['Prod'].sum()/grp['FWeight'].sum()
print(result)
```

**Output** with your data: **Dummy Data (B)**

```
vid2               COS
-_aaMGK6GGw_57_61  2      0.238485
-_hbPLsZvvo_18_25  1      0.275962
-_hbPLsZvvo_5_8    2      0.307548
dtype: float64
```

### Dummy Data: A

I made the following dummy data to test a few aspects of the logic.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'vid2': [1,1,2,5,2,6,7,4,8,7,6,2], 
                   'COS': [2,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,2,3], 
                   'fsim': np.random.rand(12), 
                   'FWeight': np.random.rand(12)})
df['Prod'] = df['fsim']*df['FWeight']
print(df)

# Groupby and apply formula
grp = df.groupby(['vid2', 'COS'])
result = grp['Prod'].sum()/grp['FWeight'].sum()
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
vid2  COS
1     2      0.405734
2     3      0.535873
4     1      0.534456
5     1      0.346937
6     2      0.369810
7     2      0.479250
8     1      0.065854
dtype: float64
```

### Dummy Data: B (OP Provided)

This is your dummy data. I made this script so anyone could easily run it and load the data as a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = """
                vid2  COS      fsim   FWeight
0  -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61    2  0.253792  0.750000
1  -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61    2  0.192565  0.250000
2    -_hbPLsZvvo_5_8    2  0.562707  0.333333
3    -_hbPLsZvvo_5_8    2  0.179969  0.666667
4  -_hbPLsZvvo_18_25    1  0.275962  0.714286
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
#print(df)
```

Comment: @Vaidehi Please take a look at the solution and let me know if you have any questions.